# Writing Complicated Constraints in Pymoo

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, pymoo

I need to write a complicated constraint in Pymoo for a scheduling problem.
for all i = 1 to 7, t = 1 to 14
sum (k in 1 to 3 ) y(i)(k)(t) <= 1

How the indices and summation could be incorporated in Pymoo constraints/ objective functions ?? please share any reference that shows an example of writing such constraint.

Here is the draft code I created using the genetic algorithm NSGA-II

```
    import numpy as np
    from pymoo.algorithms.moo.nsga2 import NSGA2
    from pymoo.core.problem import Problem
    from pymoo.optimize import minimize
    from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation

class MyProblem(Problem):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=294, # since y is 3 indexed variable (7*3*14)
                         n_obj=1, 
                         n_constr=56, # Constraint is written for all i range(4 to 7) & all t range (1 to 14) Total (14*4)
                         xl=np.array([0, 0, 0]),
                         xu=np.array([v, 1, 1]),
                         ElementwiseProblem=True)
        
    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        
        #f1 = Here the Obj. Function

        #g1 = Jere is the Constraint

        out["F"] = [f1]
        out["G"] = [g1]

Problem = MyProblem()
algorithm = NSGA2(pop_size=40,
                 n_offsprings=10,
                 sampling="real_random",
                 crossover="real_sbx", prob=0.9, eta=15,
                 #mutation="real_pm", eta=20,// eta repeated error 
                 eliminate_duplicates=True)

stop_criteria = ('n_gen', 60)
results = minimize(
          problem = problem,
           algorithm = algorithm,
           termination =stop_criteria)
```

Comment: If this is still not solved, can you explain what exactly is your objective function and what are your constraints